# Pyinstaller - Hide and Run Executable file through .bat file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I am trying to add one executable (.exe) file, a .conf file and a .bat file into the binary package created by pyinstaller and then through that binary package i want to call the .bat file that will send some commands to .exe and that exe will pick the configuration file from .conf and do its work.

** Example **

1. Click on Run button from Python Package.
2. Python Package runs .bat file inside it.
3. .bat file calls .exe with arguments
4. .exe picks config from .conf file and do its work

Comment: What is the error? Where you are stuck? What have you tried till now?

Comment: @py_saad i have no idea how to run that .bat file and how it will run the .exe

Comment: All the instructions are written in .bat and you run it by double click it. At the end of .bat file, add pause to check if there is any error while execution. If you don't add pause, console will appear and it will disappear instantly

Comment: @py_saad you didnt get me, i am adding those files to python package made using pyinstaller by --add-data attribute. How to run that .bat file inside python .exe package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you create the binary through pyinstaller:

1. [Add files (.conf and .bat and .exe) to the bundle](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle) using the `Analysis` call in the .spec file. 
   When you run the binary created through pyinstaller it unpacks itself at a temporary location in AppData on Windows by default. You should be able to get that path through `sys._MEIPASS`
2. In the python script run the .conf, .bat and .exe files preferably using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: Thank You, I already found this answer and it is the same as yours one :)